# django postgresql url unix socket

Tags: django, postgresql, sockets, unix

I've read the Django docs and other references to using PostgreSQL over Unix sockets with Django, but am stuck trying to find the correct format (if possible) using a DB URL in a .env file.

My current DB conn parameter in my env file is:

```
DATABASE_URL="psql://sqluser:passwd@127.0.0.1:5432/dbname"
```

I tried:

```
DATABASE_URL="psql://sqluser:passwd@/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432/dbname"
```

I have MD5 set for the sqluser on the dbname in pg_hba.conf but with this I get:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "sqluser"
```

My pg_hba.conf:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   dbname          sqluser                                 md5
local   all             all                                     peer
```

PSQL logs show the user ID is passed, but conflicts with the Unix user as an error, as it seems to want to use the peer method and not the MD5.